# Can I backup a SQL Server 2005 database using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 

Tags: backup, sql-server-express

My goal is to work with a client's 2005 database using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. When I am finished I would like to restore the database in it's 2005 format.

Could someone post the process for backing up a 2005 database in 2008 R2 and or the link.

Thank you,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, no process, no tools, no "hack", no workaround to do this. **It just won't work**. If you've "upped" a SQL Server database to 2008 R2 level, there's **no way back** to 2005. None. Zilch. Nada. Period.

If you need to work with your client's SQL Server 2005 database  and you need to be able to return it back to your client, you either need to install a SQL Server 2005 version on your machine (Express will be fine, as long as you don't exceed the 4 GB size limit), or you need to "ship back" all changes/modifications as SQL scripts which can be executed against the SQL Server 2005 version.

Comment: There was a database format version bump in SP2 for SQL Server 2005 (from 611 to 612), so if your customer is using SP1 or earlier make sure you do so too, or otherwise you may upgrade the database format to SP2 format and the customer won't be able to use it without applying SP2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with the following steps:

Go to the Registry Editor "regedit32" and there find Microsoft SQL Server Instance under "HKEY_Local_...". There you need to rename 90 to "Old90" same "90" you can also find in "wow...", also rename that to "old90". Now install SQL Server 2008. Once SQL Server is installed you need to rename the newly created folder "90" to "70" at the same location in  the registry. Now rename back old folders "Old90" to "90". Now you will have both version, on you machine.